# Read hive table (or HDFS data in parquet format) in Streamsets DC

Tags: hive, hdfs, streamsets

Is it possible to read hive table (or HDFS data in parquet format) in Streamsets Data collector? I don't want to use Transformer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the raw files in parquet is counter to the way that data collector works so that would be a better use case for transformer.

But I have successfully used the jdbc origin either from Impala or hive to achieve this, there are some additional hurdles to jump with the jdbc source.